# why scala list result is this, is follow,please thanks you

Tags: scala

为什么`List (1 , 2 , 3) :: List (4 , 5 , 7 , 8 , 9) :: List (10, 11 , 12)` 
的运算结果是`List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 10, 11, 12)`；而不是`List (1 , 2 , 3) :: List (4 , 5 , 7 , 8 , 9) :: List (10, 11 , 12)`这个呢？求解

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is `::`, but if you want to join the contents of all the lists, you need to use `:::` (one more `:`)

Comment: 我的意思是List(1,2,3) :: List(4,5,6,7,8,9) :: List(10,11,12)的操作结果为什么不是List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(10, 11, 12))呢？？？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cons" method `::` is for adding a new element to the head of a `List`.

```
val pet = 'c' :: List('a', 't')  //pet: List[Char] = List(c, a, t)
```

So what happens when you do this: `List(4,5,7,8,9) :: List(10,11,12)`? You are adding one new element of type `List[Int]` to a list of `Int`s. The result is a list with four elements: `List[Int],Int,Int,Int`. Since types `Int` and `List[Int]` are unrelated, the result is type `List[Any]`.

```
val bad = List(4,5,7,8,9) :: List(10,11,12)
//bad: List[Any] = List(List(4, 5, 7, 8, 9), 10, 11, 12)
```

Extrapolate to one more `List[Int]` element and you can see why it returns the result you're getting.

```
val notGood = List(1,2,3) :: List(4,5,7,8,9) :: List(10,11,12)
//notGood: List[Any] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 7, 8, 9), 10, 11, 12)
```